# Expressing an integer as a sum of integers with minimum variance

Tags: java, android, integer

I want to know how I can express an integer as a sum of integers with minimum variance. For ex : 21 can be expressed as 6+6+6+3 or 6+5+5+5 or 18+1+1+1 or ..... But the set (6,5,5,5) has the minimum variance. I want to program in android which can do this, given an integer and the number of elements in the set.

Comment: How many numbers you want in the set? Always 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try just dividing by the numbers in the set (21/4 = 5) and then adding the reminder to  the numbers in the set

For example, take 23.

- Divide 23/4 = 5
- take the reminder 23%4 = 3
- add one to each number of the set, until the reminder is 0.
- result = 6,6,6,5

Comment: >>`Divide 24/4 = 5` + `take the reminder 24%4 = 4` and this w/ positive voting (+3), not like the method is wrong or something but superbly funny

Comment: hahaha, that's why I do TDD on my real code :), thanks for spotting the error :)... And I need to sleep. See you tomorrow SO

Comment: also it might be incorrect, imagine this: you have to represent 3 w/ a set of 7 numbers, the obvious choice is 6 times zero, and one time 3, but w/ the method you get 1-1-1, 0-0-0-0; adding the '1' would be trickier

Comment: math is easy, arithmatic is hard.

Comment: Thanks a lot Augusto!! Thats the answer I was looking for.